# Getting Rails 5 app to return JSON API format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, json-api

I'm trying to get my app to return in lowercase camelcase for eventual JSON API formatting.

I've installed `gem 'active_model_serializers'` and created a new initializer with the following code in it:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
```

Then I have a small API that returns json, as all of the best internet applications do:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
  def sky
      @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

      if @user
          obj =  {
              sky: {
                  sectors: @user.sectors,
                  slots: @user.slots
              }
          }

          render json: obj
      else
          raise "Unable to get Sky"
      end
  end
```

More on the API controller inheritance pattern: `class API::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base`

**The Problem**

In my API response, things are still snake cased and I see this error in the console `[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null` but my research has led me to a dead end as to what to do.

Any suggestions would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: This is a rails app, not a rails-api app, fwiw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not calling an active record serializer in your controller, so those config settings  aren't being picked up.

**Solution**:
Create a `UserSerializer` in `"app/serializers/user_serializer.rb"` that should look something like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_many :sectors
  has_many :slots
end
```

as well as similarly structured `SectorSerializer` and a `SlotSerializer` with all of the attributes you want from each (Here are the [getting started docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/getting_started.md) and the [general syntax docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md) for active record serializers)

Then in your controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
  def sky
    @user = User.includes(:sectors, :slots).find_by_id(params[:user_id])

    if @user
      render json: @user
    else
      raise "Unable to get Sky"
    end
  end
end
```

Which will eager load :slots and :sectors with [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) then calls your `UserSerializer` using your camel_case config options.

Comment: No. It's still camel cased

Comment: snake cased, rather

Comment: @zack which version of active model serializers are you using?

Comment: run `bundle show | grep active_model_serializers` to get the version

Comment: `active_model_serializers (0.10.6)`

Comment: So after doing some more reading, I don't think active model serializers should even be called here. Also, which keys aren't being camel cased? From your example it looks like they're all one word.

Comment: I don't think active model serializers should be being called since you're not calling `render json: @an_instance_of_a_model` and you're not explicitly invoking a serializer. Are you using it elsewhere in your app?

Comment: Also, which keys aren't being camelCased? it looks like all of your keys are one word

Comment: `@user.sectors` is an array of `Sector` objects, same with `@user.slots`. Those keys like `user_id` and `sector_number` aren't camelcased

Comment: do you have a UserSerializer defined in "app/serializers/user_serializer.rb"?

Comment: I don't. I haven't built any serializers

Comment: @zack ok, well that could be the problem -- It might be looking for a user serializer and when it's not there it just spits out that `Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null` error

Comment: @zack any luck?

Comment: I got swamped yesterday. Gonna try this afternoon. Thanks for your help so far George, really appreciate it. Will report back soon

Answer (score 3):

In your controller put respond_to :json

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController

  respond_to :json
```

and in the action put same that you have

```
def sky
   ...      
   render json: obj
   ...       
end
```

and define in base controller

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

Comment: Still snake cased

Answer (score 2):

From this pull request (*) it looks like you should be able to configure `key_format = :lower_camel` in your ActiveModel::Serializers config.

(*) https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/534

Answer (score 2):

i think it helps you. in my case i use `gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.5'` which depends on `case_transform (>= 0.2)`

and in `rails console` i can do

```
CaseTransform.camel_lower(initially_serialized_output)                                                       
=> {:name=>"My Company", :jsonThings=>{:rating=>8, :aKey=>{:aSubkey=>{:anotherKey=>"value"}}}}
```

my research was by steps:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1993 => https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/case_transform-rust-extensions

did you find this?

Comment: initially_serialized_output = {
  "name": "My Company",
  "json_things": {
    "rating": 8,
    "a_key": {
      "a_subkey": {
          "another_key": "value"
        }
    }
  }
}